# Java-based WebRTC SFU implementation for Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, webrtc, sfu

I'm currently working on a project where users can create rooms using WebRTC technology. While I'm comfortable with the front-end implementation, I'm seeking guidance on how to integrate WebRTC SFU (Selective Forwarding Unit) functionality into my Spring Boot backend.

I've explored options like mediasoup and Kurento, but they are primarily for Node.js environments. Since my project is based on Spring Boot, I'm looking for Java-based alternatives.

Could someone recommend a Java library or provide insights on implementing WebRTC SFU in a Spring Boot application? Scalability is a crucial factor for my project, so solutions that can handle large numbers of concurrent connections effectively would be preferred.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or suggestions.